# Clicking Network Profile is broken

Tags: bug, status-norepro, network-profile

I was looking at my [user profile](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/52/dforck42) on Movies & TV and clicked on *Network Profile*.

Why am I getting [an error](https://stackexchange.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/users/34022/dforck42) when I do so?

Comment: this sounds familiar: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357708/so-profile-page-not-opening

Comment: I can see your user and network profile without any issue.

Comment: Can you view it in an anonymous window (not logged in)?

Comment: it's working now